# How to make custom Radio-Button labels in ZF2 forms?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form2

I have a form with Radio-button:

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'time',
    'options' => [
        'value_options' => [
            '0' => '9:00 - 12:00',
            '1' => '12:00 - 16:00',
            '2' => '16:00 - 19:00',
        ],
        'label_attributes' => [
            'class' => 'WW_OBJ_fm-label',
        ]
    ],
    'type' => 'Radio'
]);
```

In the view I make the output like this:

```
<div> 
<?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('time')); ?>
</div>
```

and  get the output (formatted for readability):

```
<div>
    <label class="WW_OBJ_fm-label">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="0"/>
        9:00 - 12:00
    </label>
    <label class="WW_OBJ_fm-label">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="1"/>
        12:00 - 16:00
    </label>
    <label class="WW_OBJ_fm-label">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="2"/>
        16:00 - 19:00
    </label>
</div>
```

But I need, that label text ist wrapped by a `<span>`:

```
<div>
    <label class="WW_OBJ_fm-label">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="0"/>
        <span class="WW_label-text">9:00 - 12:00</span>
    </label>
    <label class="WW_OBJ_fm-label">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="1"/>
        <span class="WW_label-text">12:00 - 16:00</span>
    </label>
    <label class="WW_OBJ_fm-label">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="2"/>
        <span class="WW_label-text">16:00 - 19:00</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

What is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three possible solutions for your problem.

1) Extend the `Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormRadio` class, overriding the `renderOptions` method, replicating almost entirely the one that you can find in `Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox` but maybe adding an option to pass optional attributes to the `span` element

2) Very subtle, but could save you writing some code: using the translator. Since the radio value options are translated, you could keep your values defined in the configuration but adding the `span` element in the transation

3) Do not use `$this->formElement` to display the element, but actually write all the html

Comment: I have already did what you wrote in solution 3. I personally prefer solution 1, but lots of duplicated code is not very attractive to me.

Comment: @GennadiyLitvinyuk I agree with you, altough it'll be just one method... other possibility is to a little refactoring and then do a pull request to the Zend guys, but that will certainly take some time

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use labelOption 'disable_html_escape' :

```
$this->add([
        'name' => 'time',
        'options' => [
            'value_options' => [
                '0' => '<span class="WW_label-text">9:00 - 12:00</span>',
                '1' => '<span class="WW_label-text">12:00 - 16:00</span>',
                '2' => '<span class="WW_label-text">16:00 - 19:00</span>',
            ],
            'label_attributes' => [
                'class' => 'WW_OBJ_fm-label',
            ]
        ],
        'type' => 'Radio'
    ]);
$element = $this->get('time');
$element->setLabelOptions(['disable_html_escape' => true]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution ist not aceptable, because the label of value-option will be used later in evaluation of the form values.